# Need clarification on the Bioshock Infinite ending

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Spoilers:

> In the end, Elizabeth and Booker realize that Booker becomes Comstock at the baptism turning point, but in an alternate reality remains the Booker Dewitt we know in the story. It is in the latter reality (Booker Dewitt's) that Booker births Anna. This event in the sequence would have to have been after the baptism turning point, and thus with Booker dying, he could not have had Anna in that reality, he would not have become Comstock in the alternate one, and he could not have joined with the Lutece's and would not have founded Columbia. So, in the end, shouldn't Booker, Comstock, Anna (Elizabeth), Columbia itself, and any other realities connected to them not exist past the baptism?

Comment: I somehow get the feeling, this kind of question is being asked a lot lately... just in slightly different forms and variations.

Comment: @Nolonar Your nose seems to be bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of the ending is to ensure this outcome. Elizabeth uses her power over the Bioshock multiverse to drown Booker at his baptism in every universe, thus preventing Comstock, DeWitt, and Elizabeth from existing in any of the universes. The various Elizabeths from different multiverses begin to disappear one-by-one after Booker's death to illustrate this fact.

Comment: So I was right... BUT THAT'S SUCH A DEPRESSING ENDING!

Comment: Watch past the credits and you might get a happier ending.